# Align icon to left button expanded

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem with button expanded in flutter, I need align the icon to the left  of the button, I made it with widget Row, because is the best way that I found. But, the text isnt centered correctly.

```
   SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () => {},
    color: Colors.blue,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: Row(
     children: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.send),
      Expanded(
       child: Text('Enviar', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
      )
     ],
    )
   ),
  ),
```

and the result is

[image]

Is there a better way to make a button with this style(text centered in all button not only in it's space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the two elements inside the Row. This code should work for you

```
SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            color: Colors.blue,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.send),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Enviar'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two common approaches you can try, I have not implemented them but I am just giving you the core ideas:

- Use a [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) and set your `Icon` to the `leading` property, and your aligned `Text` to the `title` property. This approach might look cleaner and easier, but I suspect you might have the same problem regarding the aligned `Text`.
- Use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and wrap your `Icon` with an `Align` widget, setting its `alignment` property to fit your needs. Then, replace your `Expanded` with a `Center` widget for your `Text`, and you will not need the `textAlign: TextAlign.center` property. I think this might work better for you.

Comment: List tile not works very well, I will try with Stack, thanks.